# ¿Cuál es el diminutivo de mano, foto, moto, etc.?

Tags: gramática, género, diminutivos

Para las palabras que son femeninas pero terminan en *o*, ¿cuál es la forma diminutiva? O sea, ¿es el diminutivo de *foto fotito* o *fotita*? Y para *mano*, ¿es *manito* o *manita*? En el caso de *mano*, creo que he visto ambas formas.

Comment: La escritora argentina María Elena Walsh, en una de sus poesías infantiles, refiriéndose al gato dice: "... atuza el bigote, lava sus MANITAS".

Comment: He escuchado «fotico»

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Según la RAE en el caso de mano se aceptan ambas aunque la norma gramatical es no cambiar la vocal final en el diminutivo independientemente del género, en [el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=mano):

> **mano. 1.** ‘Parte del cuerpo que comprende desde la muñeca hasta la punta de los dedos’. Es femenino: *la mano*. Para el diminutivo son válidas las formas *manito* y *manita*. Lo habitual en la formación de los diminutivos de nombres que acaban en *-a* o en *-o* es que el sufijo conserve la misma vocal final del sustantivo, independientemente de cuál sea el género gramatical de este:
>
> *la casa > la casita, el mapa > el mapita, el cuadro > el cuadrito, la moto > la motito.*
>
> En el caso de *mano*, excepcionalmente, se han generado ambas formas; así, *manito*, que mantiene la -o final del sustantivo, es la forma habitual en la mayor parte de América:
>
> > *«Saluda a Cámara con la manito»* (Cuzzani Zorro [Arg. 1988]);
>
> y *manita*, que se ha generado atendiendo al género gramatical del sustantivo *mano*, y no a su vocal final, es la forma que se usa habitualmente en España y en México:
>
> > *«Nomás se despidió con la manita»* (Monsiváis Ofensiva [Méx. 1979]).
>
> Menos frecuente es el diminutivo *manecita*, también correcto:
>
> > *«Él, enamorado, apretaba más la tierna manecita»* (Derbez Usos [Méx. 1988]).

Comment: Un pequeño "regionalismo". En México "manito" se usa más bien para referirse a alguien, por ejemplo "como estás manito?" En algunos círculos ese uso se puede considerar como de gente con un bajo nivel educativo. Por lo mismo si dices "manito" para referirte a la mano es probable que te vean raro o no te entiendan.

Comment: @Sergio: "manito" viene de "mano", otra manera de refereirse a alguien. Y "mano" viene de "hermano"... En cualquiera de las tres variantes el uso es de caraderia y no siempre denota un bajo nivel social.

Comment: @Rodrigo: En el contexto del que Sergio está hablando: "manito" viene de "hermanito" y "manita" viene de ambos "hermanita" y "mano". Ejemplos: "Ay manita, qué miedo!", "Hijito, dame la manita para ponerte el guante!"

Answer (score 1):

Como la palabra "mano" termina en `-o` y aunque sea femenina, yo imaginaría que el diminutivo sería "manito".
Para dar un ejemplo, el diminutivo de sistema es "un sistemilla" and not "un sistemillo", y la misma regla aparecería para problema: "el problemita".

Comment: 'Manita' es definitivamente correcto. Quizás 'manito' lo sea también, pero personalmente nunca lo he oído y me sonaría algo raro.

Comment: Acá en Chile se usa prácticamente siempre `manito`. `Manita` igual se entiende, pero suena mucho más como español mexicano.

Answer (score 0):

Soy argentina y vivo en España. Les puedo contestar respondiendo a una lógica: Moto=Motito, Foto=Fotito, Mano=Manito. Por regla general se mantiene la -o del sustantivo original. No es correcto decir que los diminutivos no se utilizan, porque en todos los países se usan, por lo tanto pido que se tenga respeto al uso que se utiliza en cada lugar, pues las lenguas son vivas, y evolucionan. Por otro lado, siguiendo el hilo, "Manita" es una excepción a la regla, por el uso masivo al cual llegó.

Comment: ¿Y en qué se diferencia esto de la respuesta aceptada?