# Diminutives of masculine words ending -a

Tags: género, sufijos, diminutivos

Following this question: [*¿Cuál es el diminutivo de mano, foto, moto, etc.?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2868/18348), and [the quote from the DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=mano) therein:

> Lo habitual en la formación de los diminutivos de nombres que acaban en *-a* o en *-o* es que el sufijo conserve la misma vocal final del sustantivo, independientemente de cuál sea el género gramatical de este: ... *el mapa > el mapita*

it seems the common method is to maintain the word's terminal vowel, independent of its gender (with the exception of *mano*).

But this doesn't seem to be the case for the most common example that comes to mind:

*papá* > *papacito, papaíto*

Is the RAE's description out of sync with common practise, or is *papá* (or words referring to male persons in general) an exceptional case, like *mano*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say *papá* is not an exception but a special case. The RAE's description refers to nouns ending in **unstressed** *-a* or *-o*, although it doesn't specifically say so. These endings are by far the most common among nouns, being the ones associated with feminine and masculine gender respectively.

Nouns ending in anything but these two unstressed vowels tend to form their diminutives by adding *-c-* before the usual suffix (*-cito, -cita* or *-cico, -cica* or *-cillo, -cilla*, etc.), using the last vowel to show the gender of the base noun. Therefore *papá > papacito* corresponds to *cajón > cajoncito* or *puré > purecito*.

If anything, *papá* is exceptional because it admits not only *papacito*, but also *papaíto* and even *papito* (the last one being truly anomalous).

Comment: is the superlative rule the same? because if we use it for padre, we can have padresote and padrecito, but also padrote

Comment: Superlatives are more varied, I think. I don't remember using or hearing a superlative for *padre*...

Comment: @pablodf76 *[padrón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RQtouix), [padrazo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RQe4RLg), [padrote](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RR59yTM)*?